# Test statistic and C.I. for population proportion

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, proportion, hypergeometric-distribution

I'm doing a test statistic and C.I. for population proportion. Can someone explain to me what are assumptions coming from hypergeometrical distribution directly to normal distribution?
As I understand, if one goes from binomial distribution, you have to ensure that:
n*p>5 and n*(1-p)>5, but what about hypergeometrical? 
Or should I just go from X~h to X~b (with proof that N>50 and n/N<0.05) and then to ~n?